# Rails: Difficult SQL query has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's my User model:

```
has_many :follower_connections, :class_name => "Following", :foreign_key => :user_id
has_many :followed_users, :through => :following_connections
has_many :followed_recommendations, 
           :through => :followed_users, 
           :source => :recommendations, 
           class_name: Recommendation
```

Recommendation:

```
has_many :ratings
has_many :recommended_trailers, :through => :movie, class_name: Trailer, source: :trailers

scope :unrated, -> (id) { 
    includes(:ratings).where("ratings.user_id != ?", id).references(:ratings)
  }
```

Rating:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recommendation
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:recommendation_id]}
end
```

Basically as a User, you can follow other users. And you can recommend movies (recommendations) to other users and see other users' recommended movies.

Each user can also rate other users' recommendations.

What I'm trying to do is load all of a given users' followed_recommendations that *have not been rated by that user* (one recommendation can be rated my many users).

I'm calling:

```
current_user.followed_recommendations.unrated(current_user.id)
```

But it's returning some recommendations that have been rated by the current_user.

Any thoughts on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: The best way to understand the reason why ActiveRecord query returns an unexpected result is to see a generated by it raw sql query.